# Importing data in R Markdown

Tags: directory, r-markdown, importerror, read.csv

I’m trying to import files into my markdown document. This is the code I used;

```
daily_activity <- read_csv(“dailyActivity_merged.csv”)
Sleep_data<- read_csv(“sleepDay_merged.csv”)
weight_log <- read_csv(“weightLogInfo_merged.csv”)
```

This is the code chunk to import my data as an R markdown document.
When I run this code, the files are imported but when I try to knit it, it comes out like a text. What can I do about it?